# I want to disable Edit Properties from a sharepoint form library

Tags: properties, form-library

I have created a sharepoint form library, with custom content type. I have an InfoPath form that creates with custom code a new items in library and copying some fields in to list columns using the allow edit properties in field's promotion.

The thing is that I only want users to edit the form using the form it self. By editing Edit Properties they can override all the rules I have applied in the form.

I know that this is happening because I have selected to promote fields to columns but I need this functionality too.

Is there any other way to disable Edit Properties?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your version.

In WSS there was no "good" or "SharePoint" way of doing this. You'd have to copy `core.js` and modify it accordingly. After that create a new masterpage wich pulls in the new `[copy]core.js`. Rather crude. But [Microsoft adviced on this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768565(v=office.14).aspx) (even for SP2010).

Starting with SP2010 you can do this by using "CustomActions". You can remove a button by emptying it's Definition. Microsoft has a [walkthrough on this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff408060(v=office.14).aspx) and there are [many examples out there](http://www.stuartroberts.net/index.php/2013/03/17/hide-sharepoint-ribbon-items/)

Also Starting from SP2010 it is posible to do this in a control's code-behind using [SPRibbon.TrimById()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spribbon.trimbyid(v=office.14).aspx)

For completeness: It is also possible to add/modify customActions using CSOM: Check [SPWeb.UserCustomActions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.usercustomactions(v=office.15).aspx)

Keep in mind, that you'd have to modify the context-menu, too.